# how to find org.eclipse.persistence maven dependency?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

how to find a maven dependency ? for example,

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

The error is

```
[WARNING] The POM for org.eclipse.persistence:javax.persistence:jar:2.0.0 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for org.eclipse.persistence:eclipselink:jar:2.0.0 is missing, no dependency information available
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project javaee: Could not resolve dependencies for project com:javaee:jar:2.0: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.ecli
    pse.persistence:javax.persistence:jar:2.0.0, org.eclipse.persistence:eclipselink:jar:2.0.0: Failure to find org.eclipse.persistence:javax.persistence:jar:2.0.0 in http:
    //repo1.maven.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -
    > [Help 1]
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the EclipseLink Maven repository to your settings: http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Maven

Comment: This didn't work for me either, <artifcatId>eclipselink</artifactId> works fine but doesn't entitle the javax.persistence.Persistence implementation. Also uncommented the <snapshot> tag in repo

Comment: found another Stack for that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003421/how-to-setup-eclipselink-with-jpa