# Jpa project where is annotation @NamedQueries

Tags: java, maven, jpa

I have a maven project and I want to work with JPA.

My pom.xml is

```
<dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.197</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

I have the following class

```
package edu.javacd.reviewservice;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.Table;

    @Entity
    @Table(name = "REVIEW")
    @NamedQueries({ @NamedQuery(name = "Review.findAll", query = "SELECT r FROM Review r"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Review.findById", query = "SELECT r FROM Review r WHERE r.id = :id"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Review.findByMovieId", query = "SELECT r FROM Review r WHERE r.movieId = :id") })
    public class Review implements Serializable {
    }
```

How  do I have to configure the pom.xml for using the annotation @NamedQueries

Comment: Your Eclipse "javax.persistence" jar has that annotation, but then you could easily open the jar and see it for yourself ...

Answer (score 0):

**Edit** : The annotation is in this package : `javax.persistence.NamedQueries`
Normally your pom.xml is already configure to you use the `@NamesQueries` annotation.

**Edit** : And you are missing the EclipseLink implementation dependency :

Check this old post : [How to setup Eclipselink with JPA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003421/how-to-setup-eclipselink-with-jpa)

Your 3 dependencies (which are external libraries) stand respectively for :

- **Edit** : JPA annotations
- Transaction Management for JPA
- JDBC Driver for H2 database

This annotation allows you list all the queries you will use in your program and their sql statements. Instead of typing directly sql statements in your code, you will have something like this:

```
Query query = em.createNamedQuery("Review.findAll");
List results = query.getResultList();
```

Comment: Not quite. The first is EclipseLink's own version of the standard JPA API jar. This is not their IMPLEMENTATION of JPA. This is the jar that includes that annotation, as I said above in my comment, to which your answer does nothing to tell the person WHY they have a problem

Comment: The pom would not be already configured to use @NamedQueries unless the persistence api (or something else that depends on it) is included as a dependency.

Answer (score 0):

You will find the [@NamedQueries](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/NamedQueries.html) annotation and the others you mention(@Entity, @Table, @NamedQuery) in the java [persistence api](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/partpersist.htm). Add its [coordinates](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.persistence/javax.persistence-api) (or those of a different library that uses it, such as Hibernate, WildFly, etc.) as a dependency in your pom.xml to use them:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
</dependency>
```